# ASP.NET Core memory inscrease on every request and GC does not free it

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

In one of our ASP.NET Core services, we noticed that the memory is increasing after every request. It is reaching about 2GB in 2 days.

I tried to investigate the issue and I discovered that the issue is (probably) with the garbage collector that it is not getting triggered.

To make investigation easier, I tried to see how things are with a simple Web API app (Dotnet Core version 2.1 created from Visual Studio template, in Debug & Release/ Self contained & IIS Express)

This brand new app has the same issue. **Memory goes up for every request and never gets released as shown in the image below.**

[image]

In the case if the system is low in memory, GC is getting [triggered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twL3K.png)  but the memory never goes down. Is this normal?

Because this is very strange, I did the same test with a simple ASP.NET on Framework 4.6. **Memory is released**.

This is very strange and not acceptable. Can anyone please explain to me what's happening with ASP.NET Core memory?

**Edit:**

As requested, here is my code, a very basic ASP.NET Core generated from Visual Studio:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
}

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

}
```

Comment: It's unlikely anyone will be able to assist unless you show some code.

Comment: I just added the code, very basic WEB API app.

Comment: I think I've got a similar issue. A test server I've spun up to test a WebAPI seems to have some issue. I've seen it take as much 5 gig of ram from which I then get out of memory exceptions. I can't seem to find any info on the subject.

Comment: Dhia, did you ever find a solution to the memory leak? I am seeing the same on .NET Core 2.2

Comment: I have same problem on asp.net core 2.1 w/centos ,and it is very simple MariaDB CRUD API,but high loading (10K per day). I switch to ASP.NET MVC 4.7 with same code w/ IIS, the problem is gone.

Comment: Did you find any workaround?

Comment: The problem exists even in ASP 5.0 core. A single requests causes framework to allocate tons of objects. Really weird.

Comment: Anyone got anywhere with this?

Comment: you need to use servergarbagecollection=false. otherwise, process things it own the whole darn hardware.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you ever found a solution but I was having the very same issue with my asp.net core 5.0 app. The solution DarthVader mentioned in the comments has worked for me. Just added the following part in the project file:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <ServerGarbageCollection>false</ServerGarbageCollection>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: this seems not work, but need more investigation

Comment: @Furkan Did you mean <ServerGarbageCollection>false</ServerGarbageCollection>

Comment: @AdnanAhmed yes indeed, my bad.